# Upgrading to linux-image-2.6.32-30-generic failed

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, apt

This morning I upgraded the server running ubuntu 10.04 to the latest kernel... except that apt-get returned an error. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't reboot, so I'm asking here to help solve the problem so I can reboot safely without compromising the machine. (It runs a network share which all the developer's SVN clients commit to - it's very important to keep downtime to a minimum). I was using webmin to send the command at the time.

http://codepad.org/7rpA7CKo

Any help would be very much appreciated!

John

Update:

`sudo apt-get install -f` didn't work, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` gave me this: codepad.org/flwNsMO8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the `nvidia-common` package, just uninstall it, and the upgrade should run smoothly again.

EDIT: If uninstalling gives an error too, I'd back up the `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common` and `/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/nvidia-common` files, remove them, and then try purging the package again.

Comment: That resulted in this error: http://codepad.org/HJGFQIKq

Comment: That results in this error: http://codepad.org/ehAss9qv

Comment: Ah, forgot about the `/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/nvidia-common` file, the same as for the `postinst.d/nvidia-common` applies.

Answer (score 2):

This should not cause any problem for  rebooting to current kernel or any other existing kernel versions. You should be able to see older working kernels while you are booting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll hold you to that if I reboot to a blinking cursor! :P

Comment: Sure. Old kernels are never automatically upgraded. A new kernel always installed as an additional package. You need to remove old kernels once you are satisfied new ones are working fine. It will automatically update the GRUB menu as well when you remove old kernels.

Comment: It's not a sufficient solution I think, because this will not repair the broken dependency in `dpkg`.

Comment: Agreed, but its comforting to know that it won't cause my system to be unusable in the future.

Comment: Does not being able to (un)install or upgrade anything qualify as "unusable"? ;)

Comment: I meant more if the kernel breaks :P

Comment: Yes, I agree it was not a solution. But I meant that inability to upgrade a kernel will not make your system unusable. That is important since he was holding on rebooting due to this failure. Thanks for pointing John to right fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` didn't work, `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade` gave me this: http://codepad.org/flwNsMO8

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia common && sudo apt-get install nvidia-common` and then reinstall kernel.

Comment: That resulted in: http://codepad.org/jr4H9X7K